# Чтения переменных Delphi

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-7

В файле .pas объявлена процедура в таком виде:

```
function TTS4App.CreateVArticle(ArtID: Integer; VArtType: Integer;
  const SerialNo: WideString; const SetNo: WideString; StartDate: OleVariant; 
  EndDate: OleVariant; EndDateON: Integer; const VArtNote: WideString): Integer;
```

Она создаёт объект в базе. Мне нужно перехватить введённые пользователем значения перед созданием объекта. Пытаюсь использовать функцию read для этого. я очень плаваю в теме, поэтому не совсем понимаю, как нужно написать функцию для этого. Пока это выглядит так:

```
function TCemptyName.NoNewVersions(SearchIntf, SbServerIntf: OleVariant): integer;
var
  k: integer;
  Input: array of Variant;
begin    
  s4Com := s4CreateVArticle.CreateVArticle(1,1,'1','1',1,1,1,'1');
  Input := (read(ArtID, VArtType, SerialNo,
  SetNo, StartDate, EndDate, EndDateON, VArtNote));
end;
```

Вопрос второй: значения задаются из клиента и мне нужно понять, могу ли я вообще использовать функцию read для этого.

Comment: Куда пользователь вводит значения, которые вы хотите перехватить? Кто вызывает CreateVArticle?

Answer (score 2):

Переопределить метод класса TTS4App на свой (наследованием или через указатель), в котором получив доступ к значениям пользователя передать их куда нужно и затем вызвать оригинальный метод с этими же параметрами.